# Citrus: Convert JMS binary message before validation

Tags: jms, citrus-framework

I want to convert a JMS binary message **before** validate it in a Citrus testcase.

I found out that I can receive a binary message like this

```
runner.receive(action -> 
action.endpoint("myJmsEndpoint")
            .messageType(MessageType.BINARY)
            .validator(new BinaryMessageValidator())
```

But then, I have to provide my own validator implementation (here `BinaryMessageValidator`) and I am losing the whole power of message validation available in Citrus.

Instead I would like to **convert the message** into a String and then use the normal **validation features of Citrus**.

The message payload is a normal XML. It is just an implementation detail of the SUT that the message is sent as JMS binary message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the binary base64 message validator (`MessageType.BINARY_BASE64`) that automatically converts the binary data stream to a base64 encoded String value. The expected message payload is then converted to a base64 encoded String, too. Just use the encodeBase64 Citrus function for that:

```
runner.receive(action -> action.endpoint("myJmsEndpoint")
        .messageType(MessageType.BINARY_BASE64)
        .payload("citrus:encodeBase64('<MyXmlMessage><content>Hello</content></MyXmlMessage>')")
```

This will perform a plain text message validation on the encoded base64 String values then.

In case you wanted to use the full Citrus XML message validator power you would need to write a custom message validator that extends from `com.consol.citrus.validation.xml.DomXmlMessageValidator`. In this custom validator you would need to do the binary to XML String conversion only on the received message on your own. You can do this with:

```
public class CustomMessageValidator extends DomXmlMessageValidator {

    @Override
    public void validateMessage(Message receivedMessage, Message controlMessage,
        TestContext context, XmlMessageValidationContext validationContext)
        throws ValidationException {

        receivedMessage.setPayload(new String(receivedMessage.getPayload(byte[].class), FileUtils.getDefaultCharset()));

        super.validateMessage(receivedMessage,
            controlMessage, context, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the `.payload()` validation seems to ignore my custom message validator. It complains that `DomXmlMessageValidator does only support message payload of type String, but was class [B`. So it seems to use the original message, not the converted one.

Comment: Finally I had time to track this down. If the message type is binary, Citrus converts the `controlMessage` to `byte[]`. That causes the error of my previous comment. When I also convert the `controlMessage` to a String in the custom message validator, both messages are converted to `String` and the validation with `.payload(expected)` works like a charm.